# LinkedLists within LinkedHashMaps

Tags: java, eclipse, linked-list, linkedhashmap

The following displays a player along with a stat line(Points, Assists, etc.). For the sake of having to create this for several players, is there any way I simplify this or am I approaching this completely wrong?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedList<Double>> chart = new LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedList<Double>>();
    LinkedList<Double> stats = new LinkedList<Double>();


    stats.add(6.8);
    stats.add(11.6);
    stats.add(11.6);

    chart.put("Micheal Jordan", stats);


    for(Map.Entry<String,LinkedList<Double>> entry: chart.entrySet()){
        String name = entry.getKey();
        LinkedList<Double> number = entry.getValue();

        System.out.println(name + " " + number);
    }
```

Comment: write a function that accepts the 'stats' and return 'chart'

Comment: a) You could and probably should create a constructor for a "Player" object with those stats as attributes, rather than having some linked list where you don't know what's what. b) It's Mich*ae*l Jordan. c) He scores _way_ more than 6.8 points per game! ;-)

Comment: I know haha. I was just thinking of better alternatives than having a constuctor with 8 or 9 different arguments.

Comment: If some object tend to have more and more optional attributes you should consider builder pattern.